# Is there any solution in ReactJs which will help me change the Title Bar of the link I will visit dynamically?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I open one url for eg.: "https:www.xyz.com" in new window using reactJs. Now when I visit the link, it will show https:www.xyz.com in the title bar.I need to rename the title-bar with different name eg.: "new tab opened".I tried using Helmet tag but it works for main page.But what I want is the new link which opens should get changed.What should I do ?

Comment: It’s as simple as `document.title = “new tab opened”`.

Comment: first visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then learn how to work with the text editor

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-helmet` to update the page title dynamically in react apps.

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

....
render(){
  return(
   <div>
    <Helmet>
      <title>New Tab Opened</title>
      <meta name="description" content="New Tab Component" />
    </Helmet>
    // Your component code here...
   </div>
  )
}
```

Refer the docs [here](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).